# How is the performing tag different from the performance tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Recently while tagging, I notice that there is a [performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag and a [performing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performing) tag. How are they different?

Comment: krismath - not a bug. Synonyms are a discussion point - they may not be different. I'll have a look through and if similar enough I can merge them.

Comment: @DrMayhem Sorry for mistagging. I am pretty new to the meta part of StackExchange.

Comment: Sounds like a definite synonym!

Comment: No worries krismath. High rep users and mods can always retag :-)

Comment: Chris - agreed. I had a quick look through questions in these tags. I'll merge.

Comment: Done - I'm also looking at performance-practice

Comment: @DrMayhem: Hmmm...I'd say performance-practice should be scrapped, and the 7 questions retagged either [performance] or/and [practice]. How's performance-practice specifically different to other types of practice?!

Comment: Yeah - that's along the lines of what I'm thinking. I'll try and get to it this evening.

Comment: `practice` is a real bad tag given how broad it is.  Most questions are covered by `technique` or other more specific tags.  But there are questions like "Where should I practice?" that I can't see an obvious tag to apply to other than `practice`.

Comment: @DrMayhem Did `performance-practice` get killed? That's a distinct concept as far as I'm concerned. [See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historically_informed_performance)

Comment: Of the tiny handful of questions tagged performance-practice, only one would have met that category, but its other tags work fine. None of the other 5 (I think it was 5) needed anything other than performance

Comment: It would be nice to do a site wide tag clean up before we graduate.